# Prolog nth1 anonymous variables

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have a List with Integers and anonymous variables and I try to find the index of a special values. Problem is as soon I'm using `nth1/3` to find the indices Prolog assigns values to the anonymous variables and therefore I find way too indices.

Example:
`List = [1,\_,1]`, where I want as result `X = 1, X = 3` from `nth1(X,List,1)`, but as stated before I get `X = 1, X = 2, X = 3`.

Comment: Anonymous variables are quite problematic in the toplevel. So you get the same as for, say `_A` except that you are not shown that answer substitution

Comment: @lurker May be **dif/2** instead of \= ?

Comment: @joel76 good catch! but eck.... I meant `(==)/2` not `(\=)/2`.

Comment: easy: `?- L=[1,_,1],nth1(X,L,V),V==1.
L = [1, _7064, 1],
X = V, V = 1 ;
L = [1, _7064, 1],
X = 3,
V = 1.
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a somewhat problematic issue hidden in your requirements: They *violate* an important declarative property called **monotonicity**. By this we mean that *adding* constraints can at most make the solution *more specific*, never more general.

For example, with the solution you posted, we get:

```
?- list_el_index([_], 1, N).
false.
```

Now I *add* a constraint by imposing an additional requirement on the hitherto free anonymous variable:

```
?- Var = 1, list_el_index([Var], 1, N).
Var = 1,
N = 0 .
```

I mean: *Come on*! We have added a *constraint*, and as a result get *more* solutions than before? Such a result is unfortunate and prevents us from reasoning in a *logical* way about this program.

The program also fails us in other respects. For example, let us ask: *Which solutions are there at all?*

```
?- list_el_index(Ls, El, I).
nontermination
```

Ideally, we would like the program to *generate* solutions in such cases! This generality is one of the foremost attractions of logic programming, and distinguishes it from more low-level paradigms.

---

One way to solve such issues is to **symbolically distinguish** the different *kinds* of elements that appear in your list.

For example, let us use:

- `u` for an *unknown* value.
- `i(I)` for an *integer* `I`.

With this new representation, your solution becomes:

```
list_el_index([i(I)|_], I, 0).
list_el_index([_|Tail], Element, Index) :-
    list_el_index(Tail, Element, Index0),
    Index #= Index0+1.
```

I have also taken the liberty to replace `(is)/2` by `(#=)/2`, to advertise and stick to more general integer arithmetic that lets us more freely reorder the goals, if necessary. Depending on your Prolog implementation, you may have to import a library to benefit from `(#=)/2`.

With this representation, your initial case becomes:

```
?- list_el_index([i(1),u,i(1)], 1, Index).
Index = 0 ;
Index = 2 ;
false.
```

This works as desired!

Importantly, we can use the predicate also *more generally*, namely to *generate* possible answers:

```
?- list_el_index(Ls, El, I).
Ls = [i(El)|_2994],
I = 0 ;
Ls = [_2992, i(El)|_3000],
I = 1 ;
Ls = [_2992, _2998, i(El)|_3006],
I = 2 ;
Ls = [_2992, _2998, _3004, i(El)|_3012],
I = 3 .
```

Due to the program's *monotonicity*, we can *fairly* enumerate solutions by *iterative deepening*:

```
?- length(Ls, _), list_el_index(Ls, El, I).
Ls = [i(El)],
I = 0 ;
Ls = [i(El), _4812],
I = 0 ;
Ls = [_4806, i(El)],
I = 1 ;
Ls = [i(El), _4812, _4818],
I = 0 ;
etc.
```

This has become possible by using a representation that lets us distinguish the cases by *pattern matching*. Consider using this approach to make your programs usable in all directions, and to make logical reasoning applicable. It is quite easy to apply by using the appropriate wrapper or constant, and greatly increases the generality of your programs.

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
 - L = [1,_,1], nth1(X, L, Y), ground(Y), Y= 1.
L = [1,_310914,1],
X = Y, Y = 1 ;
L = [1,_310914,1],
X = 3,
Y = 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lurkers hint, I came up with this solution.

```
list_el_index([El1|_], El2, 0) :-
    El1 == El2.
list_el_index([_|Tail], Element, Index) :-
    list_el_index(Tail, Element, Index1),
    Index is Index1+1.
```

Comment: Yes, because it should be list_el_index(L,1,X).

Comment: Ok you don't use nth1 signature !